# Plotting an existing MATLAB plot into another figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I used the plot command to plot a figure and then changed lots of its properties using set command. I also store the handle of the plot (say h1).

What I need is to use the handle to plot the same figure again later in my code. I checked the plot command and did not find any version that accepts handle. I also thought of getting the Xdata and Ydata and use them to re-plot the same figure.

What is the simplest solution?

Edit 1: A working sample code based on copyobj that PeterM suggested.

```
hf(1) = figure(1);
plot(peaks);

hf(2) = figure(2);
plot(membrane);

hf(3) = figure(3);
ha(1) = subplot(1,2,1);
ha(2) = subplot(1,2,2);

for i = 1:2
    hc  = get(hf(i),'children');
    hgc = get(hc, 'children');
    copyobj(hgc,ha(i));
end
```

Edit 2: I also found [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6459-figs2subplots) that can copy figures (including legend) into a subplot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into this situation before.  Depending on what you are trying to do the function [copyobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) may be appropriate.   This function lets you take the contents of one axes and copy it to a new figure.

Answer (score 5):

Improving @PeterM nice answer, one easier way would be:

```
fig2H=copy(gcf) % or change gcf to your figure handle
```

But it depends on what you want, if you want only the axes, or the whole figure… (btw, it doesn't seem to copy the legend handle).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `saveas` to save the figure in a file, and the `open` to load the exact same figure from this file.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the laziest way to accomplish what you want.

```
% Sample plot
f1 = figure(1);
plot(0:0.1:2*pi, sin(0:0.1:2*pi));
f2 = figure(2);

% The code you need
saveas(f1, 'temp.fig')
f2 = hgload('temp.fig')
delete('temp.fig')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function [figs2subplots](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6459-figs2subplots) (given in Edit2 in the original question) - it does the work and is very easy to use.